# Ошибка в простом коде

Tags: javascript

```js
use strict;

let age = prompt("Введите число", "");

if(age>=14 && age<=76){
 alert("Правильно");
}
```

Comment: Синтаксиса вида `use strict;` в javascript не существует.

Comment: `prompt` возвращает строку, чтобы получить число, надо перед этой функцией поставить `+`, вот так `let age = +prompt(...`

Answer (score 4):

`use strict` - должен быть строкой

```js
"use strict";

let age = prompt("Введите число", "");

if(age>=14 && age<=76){
 alert("Правильно");
}
```